# Documentation system that allows for reusability and Markdown support?

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

I'm investigating different documentation systems for a project keeping up. Most recently I've been using DITA and the DITA OT, but its complexity makes me want to shoot myself.

Are there any systems that provide the following functionality:

- Markdown support
- Reusable content (I can refer to previously defined paragraphs or terms)
- Localization support
- Preferably, free or open source
- Preferably, allows for multiple output

I wish I could use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for this, but it doesn't appear to support reusable content.

Edit: I just ended up writing my own library for this: https://github.com/gjtorikian/markdown_conrefs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind reStructuredText instead of markdown, [Sphynx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html) is worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandoc + pre or post processor.

That way you could easily implement snippet reuse.

Comment: Thanks, but I just ended up writing my own library: https://github.com/gjtorikian/markdown_conrefs :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic close to my heart. There's quite a lot of Markdown processor options out there, but at time of writing those are more a case of personal solutions to this persistent problem. We all tend to get frustrated, make something to help in the short term, and share it.

The challenge has been to extend this to something built for purpose and at scale. Which is where I've turned my focus to over the last few years. That includes first working on PressGang CCMS inside of a tech writing team at Red Hat, and then being inspired to spin out Corilla, a dedicated technical writing startup building the tool you require.

#### PressGang (the prototype)

Please refer to the [PressGang CCMS](http://pressgang-ccms.github.io/) project for an idea of what we did at Red Hat to build tools to solve this. The lead engineer did a [run-through video](https://vimeo.com/54986436) that you can see on Vimeo, and I've created a public Amazon AMI if you wish to try it. It's not being maintained but it's all open source.

It's a relatively large stack written for the most part in Java, but was useful as a look into an open source project in this space. But with bias I'd suggest...

#### Corilla (the product)

We cofounded [Corilla](http://corilla.com/) as an open source company to focus on bringing together the elements of content reuse and collaboration with the ease of Markdown and Asciidoc. I've spent years writing DocBook XML, and quickly built my own [snippets for Sublime Text](https://github.com/ddri/Sublime-Text-DocBook-XML-Snippets) to minimise the considerable overhead of authoring in that markup. The tide is of course turning. We need easier ways to write faster, and we need them to be discoverable, reusable, and allow the entire team to generate the content in formats they require.

I'd encourage you to get involved with the beta, as the technical writing and developer community is driving the project, and as we solve our problems together. Being able to resource and drive this to market is far more rewarding than having to pick through incomplete processor chains. I've been there, it's time we did more.